# Python objects qualified for function overloading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm learning Python lately (Dec.'20) and found this concept is very convoluted. Let's say I have a function. How can I tell if a particular objects `type` can be applied to this kind of `function overloading`?

```py
def compute(a, b, c):
    return (a+b) * c
```

It works fine with some of these object type - number, string, but not others.

```py
>>> a, b, c=1,2,3
>>> a, b, c = 'hi', 'U', 3   # okay

>>> a, b, c = [1], [2,3], 3  # okay
>>> a, b, c = {1}, {2}, 3    # it's set()
```

Comment: This is because strings and matrices can have maths done to them. `"string" * 3 = "stringstringstring"` however where you have used {} curley bracket. These cannot have maths done to them

Comment: @Evorage that's too broad of a statement. `{1} - {2}` is legal. The problem is that sets don't support `+`.

Comment: This isn't function overloading, python doesn't have function overloading. Python is a dynamically typed language, and this is resolved at runtime when the function is called. To know what inputs a function expects you must read the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Taking the `+` as an example, a data type must implement the `__add__()` (magic/special/"dunder") method to meaningfully use the `+` operator. In your examples, it is defined for integers, strings and lists, but not for sets.

The [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) is the reference document if you want to learn more about this topic, but as a starting point you may find [this article](https://realpython.com/operator-function-overloading/) useful.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers!  Will read and dive in... Appreciate it. Sorry that I cannot vote yet...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether a particular object, say `x` has an operator overloaded, or what we call [magic method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) in Python, you can check:

```
hasattr(x, '__add__')  # for + and similarly for any other.
```

Of course, you can define one such method for a class you want, if it does not exist.